# Grouping dictionaries by common keys

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries

```
dictlist = [{0:1,1:1,2:1,3:1}, {0:1,1:0,2:1,3:0}, {0:1,1:0,2:0,3:1}]
```

I need output as dict, where value of each key is list of values of that key in individual dicts.

```
dict_needed = {0:[1,1,1],1:[1,0,0],2:[1,1,0],3:[1,0,1]}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. Unfortunately for you, we don't do other people job here, but we help them doing theirs. Please show use some (possibly failed) attempt.

Comment: hey what kind of way is that of talking to people? I'm a seasoned programmer and have worked for many years on different languages but not on python. If you can't help just don't comment. I can easily beat you in any programming challenge you can think of, you want to try out?

Comment: @user1746774:  Although hivert's comment was lacking in tone, your response comes across as quite immature.

Comment: @hivert you may wish to consider using [this comment](http://sopython.com/wiki/useful-comments#new_user_low_quality) in the future.

Comment: @Jon Clements : Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: @user1746774 : I'm not an english native speaker and I don't meant to be rude here.

Comment: Knowledge is for sharing I think that's why this platform was built in first place. Thanks any will post my attempt from next question on wards, I could have done that this time too, but as I am new here didn't know that people will start crying over this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict
dict_needed = defaultdict(list)
for d in dictlist:
    for k, v in d.iteritems():
        dict_needed[k].append(v)
```